Stabilizing an offset wood bunk bed
So my wife and I put this offset twin over twin bunk bed together for our 2 boys yesterday.  Made sure everything is nice and tight.  Unfortunately it rocks/sways back and forth a good amount. This happens when our little one goes to the top bunk and moves. When moving it from a top corner post,  the bed seems like it will collapse.  We thought about lag bolting it to the studs and installing an x brace on the far left side (2nd pic) We verified everything is nice and tight and was hoping for some advice.



Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Just wanted to mention, I'm rather shocked that a commercial item of this type has that much rocking after assembly! Do you know what the material is under the paint by any chance?


We thought about lag bolting it to the studs

That is most definitely an option, and a very good one, although today it would frequently be the advice to use what are termed 'construction screws' instead. Old-fashioned though they may be considered, lag bolts/lag screws can be a lot cheaper and will assuredly be strong enough for this application.

and installing an x brace on the far left side (2nd pic)

If you did the above it's very likely you wouldn't feel any need to add additional bracing. So if you choose to screw to the wall I would do that first, then assess if you think you need to do anything further.
In addition to the added stability screwing to the wall secures the whole thing in place. The downside is exactly that, it secures it in one place. However, it can be unfastened from the wall and re-fastened numerous times without any problems, if you're careful (especially about not over-tightening).
If you want to leave it freestanding however...
As per my Answer that was coincidentally posted just two days ago, how do you feel about simply screwing on a couple of panels?
Panels offer certain advantages.

It may be the cheaper option (depending on what wood you had in mind for the bracing).
Whatever material you choose is ready to go immediately (no acclimation necessary).
Panels are simpler to cut than the wood for cross-bracing (no angled cuts) and may be simpler to install.
I would argue they look better.
They're safer (no spaces for a hand or foot to get trapped).
And last but not least, they provide potential surfaces for adding hangers to increase storage, at the outside left and maybe underneath.


X bracing, both at the left side as you describe and on the adjacent side (against the wall) under the high twin will go a long way to stiffening.
Lagging into a stud would also be terrific (especially for boys!) but you’d have to do a little work to space it out from the wall to clear the baseboard heaters, so try that if the x braces don’t do enough.

I'd add a horizontal board between the bed frame and the wall, fastened into both with corner braces:


It can be fastened into wall studs and bed posts even if they don't line up, just put corner braces where you can

Prevents the bed frame from moving in both horizontal directions

Prevents the child from falling between the bed frame and the wall and getting stuck

All the screw heads are hidden on the underside

The board should be thick enough for strong screws, and wide enough to clear the bed from the baseboard heaters

It acts as a small bedside table, which should be convenient, I guess the kid will need at least a lamp


The next think I'd change would be to thicken the steps on the ladder, because they look quite uncomfortable.

Dunno why this got a downvote… it’s a perfectly cromulent idea.
